# Stored procedure unable to compare

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.6

Hi I tried implementing the below stored procedure which always takes my if condition as true and implements .

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertOpen`(in uid varchar(11),in S_ID varchar(20))
BEGIN
    if(SELECT COUNT(Slot_ID) FROM smart_scheduler1.work_schedule where Employee_ID=uid AND Schedule_ID=S_ID = 0) THEN

        UPDATE `smart_scheduler1`.`work_schedule` SET `Employee_ID`=uid WHERE `Schedule_ID`=S_ID;
        ELSE
        SELECT COUNT(Slot_ID) FROM smart_scheduler1.work_schedule where Employee_ID=uid AND Schedule_ID=S_ID;

END IF;
END
```

My question is how do I compare a query with a value or integer in stored procedure if condition?

I am novice in Database , please help me. I would be very pleased if you could get me a good tutorial on stored procedure as I was not able to find much materials on stored procedures online.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for saying `COUNT(SLOT_ID)` instead of `COUNT(*)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` condition should actually almost always be `false`, unless you have an entry where `schedule_id = 0`.

It may be surprising, but in MySQL you can write something like this:

```
root@localhost:(none) > select 1=1=1;
+-------+
| 1=1=1 |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root@localhost:(none) > select 1=1=2;
+-------+
| 1=1=2 |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

So in your case you actually don't compare anything in your `if` condition, there is just a query which returns a number. And the `if` condition is `true` whenever it's not `0`.

The solution here is to use parantheses.

```
IF((SELECT COUNT(Slot_ID) FROM smart_scheduler1.work_schedule where Employee_ID = uid AND Schedule_ID = S_ID) = 0) THEN
```

Or you could do

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT Slot_ID FROM smart_scheduler1.work_schedule where Employee_ID = uid AND Schedule_ID = S_ID) THEN
```

I personally like to use `(NOT) EXISTS` very much, not only because it's so easily readable, but `EXISTS` stops as soon as an entry is found and doesn't continue to search till the very end, although the exact number is of no interest.

If the exact number matters, you can of course also use variables like this:

```
SELECT @my_variable := COUNT(Slot_ID) FROM smart_scheduler1.work_schedule where Employee_ID=uid AND Schedule_ID=S_ID
IF(@my_variable = 0) THEN
```

or

```
DECLARE my_variable INT;
SELECT COUNT(Slot_ID) INTO my_variable FROM smart_scheduler1.work_schedule where Employee_ID=uid AND Schedule_ID=S_ID
IF(my_variable = 0) THEN
```

You can read about the differences of these two kinds of variables [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) and [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-variables.html).

Comment: thanks a lot , not sure why but it did not work ..  the ELSE statement executes only when there is data already present in the table . or else it just updates without checking if there is any repeated values in slot_ID

Comment: What did you do exactly? With a simple "it did not work" I can not help you.

Comment: it just executes skipping the if not exist or if condition .. tried all the above statements

Comment: How do you know, this is not correct behaviour? Have you checked your data?

Comment: Guess I shuld do the same , i created a simple table which implemented the query , but was not able to implement the query in my database.

Comment: but thanks again your solution was correct but not sure what is wrong with my database.

Comment: do you think the relationship with foreign key could effect the current tables data .??

Comment: Not sure, what you mean. You can specify for example `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` with a foreign key, which means that when you delete a parent record, the child record(s) get deleted as well. Same for `update` in this example. When you don't specify that when creating the foreign key, the only effect a foreign key has on data is, that you can't insert a child record, when there's no parent record.

Comment: i got that the table database is already said to cascade... any way guess i will figure out something thanks ,,,